# Auto increment / Sum one field of the query result?

Tags: mongodb

I explain with an example:

I have a collection with 1 Million Items with ID: 123 each worth a different value:"worth"

user x with MONEY can "buy" the items. i basically want to  know how many items the user can buy in a most elegant way.

so i got.

```
db.items.find({Item_ID:123},{Item_Age:1,Item_worth:1}.sort({Item_age:1})
```

-> gives me all Items with Item_ID:123 sorted by age.

I could now

- Iterate through all items till Sum of Item Worth == User_Money but somehow i think this is not really efficient if the List returned matches 1 Million items and user might have only enough money for 1000

or

- do the loop and query 1000 times

or

- limit the query to 100 items. but this is very variably could still result in alot of loops

SO is there a query method which returns the sum of all values in each document??
Or any other efficient suggestions might be helpfull.

Thanks

Comment: So you're wanting the first X items, sorted by Item_age, where the total Item_worth is less than or equal to User_Money?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better than iterating would be do to this with [mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) to get the running total for the items, and then filter the result.

So define a mapper as follows:

```js
var mapper = function () {

    totalWorth = totalWorth + this.Item_Worth;

    var canBuy = userMoney >= totalWorth;

    if ( canBuy ) {
        emit(
            {
                Item_ID: this.Item_ID,
                Item_Age: this.Item_Age
            },
            {
                worth: this.Item_Worth,
                totalWorth: totalWorth,
                canBuy: canBuy
            }
        );

    }

}
```

This accumulates a variable for `totalWorth` with the current "worth" of the item. Then a check is made to see the current `totalWorth` value exceeds the amount of `userMoney` that was input. If not, then you don't emit. Which is automatic filtering.

All the emitted keys are unique so just run the mapReduce as below:

```js
db.items.mapReduce(
    mapper,
    function(){},              // reduce argument is required though not called
   {
      query: { Item_ID: 123 }
      sort: { Item_ID: 1, Item_Age: 1 },
      out: { inline: 1 },
      scope: { 
          totalWorth: 0,
          userMoney: 30 
      }, 
   }
)
```

So looking at the other parts of that :

- **query:** Is a standard query object you use to get your selection
- **sort:** Is not required really because you are looking at `Item_Age` in ascending order. But if you wanted the oldest `Item_Age` first then you can reverse the sort.
- **out:** Gives you an inline object as the result that you can use to get the matching items.
- **scope:** Defines the *global* variables that can be accessed by the functions. So we provide an initial value for `totalWorth` and pass the parameter value of `userMoney` as how much money the user has to buy.

At the end of the day the result contains the filtered list of the items that fall under the amount of money the user can afford to purchase.

Comment: wow great answer. i looked into map reduce but couldnt get my head around it this is perfect thanks A LOT!

Comment: You''l see that the output is a bit "funky" but that is how mapReduce does it. Still, it skips some steps and processing is just code. Glad it helped.